# jQuery Alert -jAlert OK click

Tags: jquery

On click of OK in jAlert nothing is triggered, even the dialog box doesn't close:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#confirm_button").click(function () {
         jAlert("Submitted", "Approval", function () {
             //My code goes in here
         }); 
     });
});
```

I need to get the event on OK click, please help me out in this!

The HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script src="jquery.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.alerts.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="jquery.alerts.css" charset="utf-8" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#confirm_button").click(function () {
                jAlert("Submitted", "Approval", function () { 
                    //
                }); 
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="btnAlert" runat="server" Text="Click"/>
    </form>
    <input id="confirm_button" type="button" value="Show Confirm" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error message(s) have you got ?

Comment: can we see how you are loading your code  maybe show us the html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jAlert` is supposed to be invoked like so:

```
$.jAlert(...)
```

Change that, and the code will work. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LhLhM/).

Comment: +1 exactly what I suggested - but the OP says the alert dialog is shown ... which it wouldnt using the code in the question !

Comment: @ManseUK: good point; that would imply that this is not the problem OP is having, but this is the only problem that is present in the given code (as our fiddles show).

Answer (score 2):

I had to make a small change to your code

```
jAlert
```

to

```
$.jAlert
```

[its working fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/uUTqE/)

Comment: Then I'm getting:  Object doesn't support property or method 'jAlert'

Comment: @user923172 you need to include [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/download) javascript library too ... are you using [this](http://dochoffiday.com/Professional/jalert-a-jquery-ui-alert-confirm-replacement) plugin ?

Comment: I have included ui libraries also and checked:   <script src="jquery-1.7.1.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.core.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>                                     Still the same error comes in

Comment: @user923172 changed my [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uUTqE/5/) to use the jAlert js code you linked to ... still working ... and Im not even using jquery UI on this one ...

Comment: For me it doesn't work, nothing happens on 'OK' Click. Its not even clickable

Comment: The issue was with IE, the jAlert Ok click was not working in IE, its working fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Is the selector named confirm_button an input? if it is, try doing this :

```
$("input[name=confirm_button").click(function () {
```

If the selector is named after a class like :

```
<a class="confirm_button"></a>
```

Then do this :

```
$(".confirm_button").click(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding the jAlert popup's OK button is "#popup_ok" meaning that's the unique ID of the instance.
So you have to bind an event to this button AFTER the jAlert function is fired.
Here I've wrapped the jAlert call inside of another function which does so:

```
function showAlert(msg, title) {
jAlert(msg, title);
$("#popup_ok").click(
  function () {
    // Do something after the OK button is clicked...
  });   
}
```

and now you call the "mother" function:

```
showAlert("Click OK if you're OK...", "Hey how are you doing?");
```