# Synchronous jquery Alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below function

```
function test()
{
  jAlert("One","DescriptionOne"); // First jAlert
  jAlert("Two","DescriptionOne"); //    Second jAlert
  window.location = 'test.html'
}
```

When run this code , the First jAlert comes and Disappears without clicking on OK button. Now the same happens with second jAlert.Finally test.html loads directly
without clicking any of the OK button. I know I have to supply a call back function but my requirement is NOT to use any call back function.

Please help me how to ,

1. Make the second jAlert wait until user clicks on OK button of first jAlert
2. Load the test.html after clicking Ok button of second jAlert.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Alert -jAlert OK click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088615/jquery-alert-jalert-ok-click)

Comment: using asynchronous functions without callbacks? good luck! see @Toverbal's answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
function test()
{
  jAlert("One","DescriptionOne", function() {
    jAlert("Two","DescriptionOne", function() {
      window.location = 'test.html';
    }) //    Second jAlert
  }); // First jAlert
}
```

Comment: Well, Using callbacks its fine. But I want the execution of next line to be blocked till the user clicks OK.Will this be possible without call back functions?

Comment: Nope, you have to do it with callbacks. You can't do it because of the event driven architecture, the whole browser would lock up if you put something like a while(!buttonPressed) in the code.