# Added jquery jAlert code inside php file but it's not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I added jAlert box inside my php code for one alert. Normal `window.confirm()` is working perfectly but I added jAlert it's not working. I include css and js file for jAlert.

```
 echo "
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">

                $.fn.jAlert({
            'title': 'Activity :- Search',
            'message': 'Are you sure you want to display more than 250 activities?',
            'theme': 'info',
            'btn': [
                {'label':'Yes', 'cssClass': 'green', 'closeOnClick': true, 'onClick': function()
                { 
                    window.location.href = ('home.php');
                } 
                },
                {'label':'No', 'cssClass': 'red', 'closeOnClick': true, 'onClick': function()
                { 
                    window.location.href = ('logout.php');
                } 
                }
            ],
            'autofocus': 'btn:first'                
        });



        </script>
    ";
```

Please help me for solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include more detail than 'it doesn't work'. Have you checked the console for any errors?

Comment: Yes i checked and it shows "TypeError: $.fn.jAlert is not a function"

Comment: It sounds like you haven't included the jAlert library in your page, or if you have the URL to the script is incorrect.

Comment: Why do you include the javascript via PHP?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I added JavaScript file in top of the page in normal way "<script type="text/javascript" src="jAlert-master/jAlert-v2-min.js"></script>"

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: @vel Yes i checked console and it shows "TypeError: $.fn.jAlert is not a function"

Comment: Try $.jAlert instead of  $.fn.jAlert. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088615/jquery-alert-jalert-ok-click

Comment: It's not $.jAlert, he's using my plugin which does use $.fn.jAlert. It appears he's not including the javascript file for the plugin before calling this.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your $.fn.jAlert in a $(function(){

It appears the plugin hasn't loaded before your code is being executed.

The final should look like this:

```
echo "
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
           $(function(){
            $.fn.jAlert({
        'title': 'Activity :- Search',
        'message': 'Are you sure you want to display more than 250 activities?',
        'theme': 'info',
        'btn': [
            {'label':'Yes', 'cssClass': 'green', 'closeOnClick': true, 'onClick': function()
            { 
                window.location.href = ('home.php');
            } 
            },
            {'label':'No', 'cssClass': 'red', 'closeOnClick': true, 'onClick': function()
            { 
                window.location.href = ('logout.php');
            } 
            }
        ],
        'autofocus': 'btn:first'                
    });

    });

    </script>
";
```